# Your connection is not private to access firebase storage files

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I'm using firebase and saved some user photos as avatar in firebase storage. Yesterday was working perfectly, I can preview the photo from downloadedURL. But today, all my user avatar showed blank. I copied the `downloadedURL` to the browser tried to directly access it, but I got below error:

```
Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from firebasestorage.googleapis.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). Learn more
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

My storage rule is like:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth!=null;
    }
  }
}
```

All visitor should be able to view the user avatar, but the user itself after logging in can have the write access. Is there anything wrong? Didn't really change the storage settings, but it just suddenly didn't work today. Please let me know. Thanks!!!

Comment: Download URLs always bypass security rules and are accessible by anyone on the internet.  The problem you're having is completely unrelated.  Perhaps you are behind a misconfigured firewall.

Comment: Will you be able to view this file ? https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/lonely-dev.appspot.com/o/xdjzikiyJhWyWFJlA0QI8zJdd2s2%2FLONELY%20DEV%20(3).png?alt=media&token=c0e33c50-70eb-48cb-8806-74fa385bb8ad

Comment: FWIW I can view that file with no SSL warnings or other issues. I think it's a problem with your firewall/proxy.

Comment: Hmm, wifi seems to have problem, phone cellular has no problem. Thanks for checking!!!