# Your connection is not private and cannot access firebase storage files

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I'm using firebase and saved some user files in firebase storage. Yesterday was working perfectly, I can preview the files by using the firebase storage URL. But today, I can't access them at all. I got below error:

It seems to suggest that the URL does not have a SSL certificate(no https) which is weird because the URL has SSL certificate yesterday.

Here's an example of my link: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:443/v0/b/joinokepos-d0051.appspot.com/o/1649579778877?alt=media&token=d480ed19-1f2d-4b6a-bc56-393392e2f51a

When I search for this URL, the 'https' is automatically canceled, as seen in the photo below.

It is suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61280995/your-connection-is-not-private-to-access-firebase-storage-files) that the firewall could be misconfigured. But I have not done anything to change the firewall and even when I try to access using different networks, all of them doesn't work(although they used to).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

[image]
[image]

Comment: The URL you shared loads without any problems for me when I click it. If the problem persists on your end, that indeed seems to suggest it is an issue with your connection rather than with Firebase Storage. I suggest trying over another connection to see if that resolves the problem, and (if so) report the issue to your network administrator.

Comment: Make sure your system date and time is set correctly. If it's using the wrong date, it might consider the certificate to be expired. Also make sure you're not using a corporate firewall or soemthing that's trying to MITM your traffic.

Comment: *firebaser here* We've heard from multiple developers in Singapore that they're having problems connecting to Cloud Storage through Firebase. So if you're in the same region, it might be caused by the same problem. I provided an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73075451/firebase-storage-only-showing-when-on-certain-vpn) and will update that as we learn more.

Comment: @Nathan, thanks for the suggestion. I've check the date and time and they are set correctly.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, yes I'm using it Singapore. Thank you for clarifying. The issue just went away all of a sudden today even though I didn't do anything. The URL can be accessed without an issue today. Do you happen to know what could have caused this?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot comment on that. It might be worth reaching out to the ISP or mobile provider to inquire why the traffic got blocked or dropped.